# Links not showing up except in IE

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Okay, it's late at night and I can NOT figure this one out. I have 11 thumbnail images on a page [HERE](http://bouquetcouture.com/bouquets.php) which are all hard coded (don't ask) and the code is IDENTICAL with exception to the filenames for the images and the query string attached to each of the link URLs.

The first two thumbnails (top left and top right) do not behave as links in Firefox, Safari, Chrome or Opera, but they DO in IE9 when hovered over (though in FF Firebug shows the link code is there) but all of the rest do. This has to be some inane jibberish I am too frazzled to see. Yet I reviewed the code over and over and nothing looks amiss.

What's worse, if I copy the code for the first two links (upper left and upper right thumbnails) and paste the code in below the first two entries, the thumbnails show up AND the links work!

Whatda...?

Any help will be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your div #mainText is large enough to go OVER the first two thumbnails. Different browsers either treat this differently or it has something to do with different takes on z-indexing or something, but decreasing the heigth of that div, or removing the height attribute (so its just as high as needed) will fix it...

Comment: This is correct. I turned off the height style for #mainText in Chrome developer tools and the top two were now clickable.

Comment: I LOVE Stack Overflow! Thank you Ceryl and fredsbend! That 500px height was from an early development phase that I overlooked as the site evolved. I can not thank you both enough! What a headbvanger. Though kinda messed up only IE let the links shine through. Again, thank you both!